# How do I use 1D arrays in a code, which I've generated using a code which is in a different IDLE file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, plot

I'm generating data as 1D arrays using some piece of code in Python v3. Next, I want to plot all these 1D arrays, but not necessarily on the same graph for comparison reasons. So how do I store these 1D arrays, and then use them in a different code file that I use to plot these arrays?

Till now, one idea that I have tried is to store these 1D arrays, while generating them, into an excel file as different columns. Next, while executing the code that plots the arrays, I can specifically call whichever array I want to plot from the excel file. However, this seems like a work-around and not an efficient method.

What I expect is this: In Python, I should be able to generate 1D arrays and store them. Later, I should be able to access these arrays in a different code file and plot these arrays or manipulate them.

Comment: What is your question? How to persist datas?

Comment: I am not from CS/IT background, so I don't know if that's the right phrase, "persist data"

Comment: Save the datas so when you exit the program the datas *persist* and aren't lost

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you want to solve is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). There are many formats, but one of the most common - JSON. Python has a module in standart library [to work with it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json). Here is the small workflow that you can use later:

Save the data in the first module:

```
import json

arrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [5,4,3,2,1]
]
with open('waka.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(arrays))
```

And load it in the second module:

```
import json
arrays = None
with open('waka.json', 'r') as f:
    arrays = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: A small stupid question: While writing an array as in the first code block, does the waka json file need to be created before writing it, or just the open as f: code line will create that waka json file?

Comment: It will be created automatically. Moreover, after `with` block it will be closed automatically.